# Does an English translation of Rashbam on Bava Batra exist on the internet?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, torah-study, translation, bava-batra

Is there an English translation of Rashbam on Bava Batra somewhere on the internet?

Comment: Boy oh boy would that be long...

Comment: @Shalom irrelevant point for AI translation, round the corner

Comment: The Artscroll Talmud, while not a literal translation, is probably mostly based on Rashbam. See Artscroll.com